# Multiselect dropdown in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var selectObj = $("<select class='custom-class1 custom-class2' " + strAttribute + "></select>");
```

Hi Guys, this is javascript for dropdown list with normal select one value only. but can i know how to add multiselect dropdown in this code for select more than one value?

Thanks.

Comment: can you please fix the **indentation** and make the code less **dense**? would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `multiple` attribute, like this...

```
var selectObj = $("<select class='custom-class1 custom-class2' multiple " +
                strAttribute + "></select>");
```

http://html.com/attributes/select-multiple/

Comment: Getting another?  Please explain what you mean or I can't help you.  Don't use images as they'll disappear one day and make this question useless for others.